# ChatterMessage sObject is not visible in salesforce org

Tags: chatter

I want to write a trigger on ChatterMessage. But in my salesforce org, I am not getting this sObject, how to get it has anyone any idea about it?

Answer (score 2):

`ChatterMessage` is split into many objects(backend objects) in Salesforce based on it's function like `FeedItem`, `FeedPost`, `FeedLike`.

> FeedItem
>
> FeedItem represents an entry in the feed, such as changes in
> a record feed, including text posts, link posts, and content posts.
> This object is available in API version 21.0 and later. This object
> replaces FeedPost.

> FeedPost
>
> FeedPost represents the following types of changes in a record feed, such as >AccountFeed: text posts, link posts, and content posts. This object is >available in API version 18.0 through 21.0. FeedPost is no longer available >in later versions. Starting with API version 21.0, use FeedItem to represent
> text posts, link posts, and content posts in feeds.

You can refer [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_list.htm) page to know further more. Then you can able to select the `SObject` for your trigger.

Please let me know if it helps.